# Ruby stdin/stdout on HackerRank

Tags: ruby

I've been trying to complete [an exercise on HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/closest-numbers?h_r=internal-search)  but am having trouble with the initial stage of "Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT". I've tried a couple of methods, among which this seems to work the best:

```
myArray = ARGF.read
newarr = myArray.split(" ").map! do |n|
    n.to_i
end
```

This returns an array, but when I run `closestNumbers(newarr)`, I get "
~ no response on stdout ~". My code works in IRB. Any ideas on where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IRB shows you the result of the last computation. For Hackerrank you need to put it in STDOUT explicitly. In a word - use `puts` for return values.

UPD: Just for reference. There is `STDOUT.write` method as well.